# $\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}log(a+e^{cx})dx$

Tags: complex-analysis, improper-integrals

I am struggling in evaluating the follow integration.

Actually, this problem not comes from complex analysis, but all my knowledge about solving these sort of problems are from complex analysis.

So I tried contour integration using infinite circle or rectangle but it does not work.

Could anyone please guide me how to approach this integral or point me to any reference materials?

## $\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}log(a+e^{cx})dx$

$a$ and $c$ are real number and $a$ is positive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not expect a closed form for
$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}\log(a+e^{cx})\,dx$$ What I should do is a series expansion
$$\log(a+e^{cx})= cx +\sum_{n=1}^\infty(-1)^{n+1}\frac{ e^{-n c x}}{n} a^n$$ which would give
$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty e^{\frac{-x^2}{2}}\log(a+e^{cx})\,dx=\sqrt{2\pi}\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n+1} \frac{  e^{\frac{c^2 n^2}{2}}}{n}a^n$$

I am not sure that the sum would converge except if $c$ is an imaginary number.

Trying for $c=i$ and a few values of $a$ gives
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
a & \text{summation} & \text{exact} \\
 0.5 & 0.71892 & 0.71892 \\
 1.0 & 1.35980 & 1.35978 \\
 1.5 & 1.92916 & 1.95724 \\
 2.0 & 2.43318 & 2.45638 \\
 2.5 & 2.87776 & 2.87839 \\
 3.0 & 3.26852 & 3.24209 \\
 3.5 & 3.61079 & 3.56096 \\
 4.0 & 3.90963 & 3.84455 \\
 4.5 & 4.16982 & 4.09974 \\
 5.0 & 4.39590 & 4.33162
\end{array}
\right)$$